# Permanent Choices in NetLogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo

In this model, if certain conditions are met, farmers invest in their Rate of Production (RoP). If other conditions are met, they invest in their Standard of Living (SoL).

Currently, this is executed via several if statements within the To Invest procedure at each time step.

How can I make the courses of action permanent. For example, if the first farm at tick 2 meets the conditions to invest in RoP, that farm should continue to do so at each subsequent time step, not have the option at tick 3 to invest in SoL. How can I make this action permanent?

```
to invest 
  let p random 100 
  set excess-prev-tick farm-excess
  if ( farm-excess > 0 and p <= 30 ) [
    set farm-RoP ( farm-RoP + farm-excess )] 
  if ( farm-excess > 0 and p > 30 and SoL < SoL-max ) [
    set SoL ( SoL + 0.1 )] 
  if ( farm-excess > 0 and p > 30 ) [
    set farm-RoC ( farm-RoC + ( count patches in-radius farm-size * 2 ))]
  if farm-excess < 0 and SoL >= SoL-min [
    set SoL ( SoL - 0.05) ]
  set farm-excess (farm-ROP - farm-RoC) 
  set RoExp ((farm-excess - excess-prev-tick) / (excess-prev-tick)) 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to create a variable for each farmer (using a farmers-own statement) that is initialised as "undecided" and then becomes either "production" or "living" when the condition is met for one of them. You should then organise your invest code to have different calculations for different subgroups of farmers (so something like `ask farmers with [invest-type = "undecided"][ <do stuff> ]`